# JSON Web Tokens: Refresh and Access

Tags: jwt

I'm writing a client app to access some server end points I've written in PHP. I'm using JWT's for authentication, and have successfully got a working system whereby people can log in with their username/password in exchange for a JWT, which can then be used to access end points until the JWT expires.

But now I'm learning about JWT Refresh Tokens (RT) and JWT Access tokens (AT).

From what I've been reading the RT expiration time should be long, to avoid annoying repeated sign-ins, whereas the AT expiration time should be short, so that should an AT be intercepted it will most likely be unusable.

However, I'm a little confused because of the following:

When an AT expires, the client must send an RT to the server to obtain a valid AT back for use.

So the RT gets transmitted and could be intercepted or possibly found in some log. So doesn't this negate the security benefits. We still have to transmit RT's to obtain AT's, so what's more secure about using RT's and AT's as opposed to just AT's with authentication?

At present I'm thinking that AT's should only last 30 seconds or so, whereas RT's should last an hour. Perhaps my timescales are wrong and I should be thinking more along the lines of RT's last a whole week, whereas AT's last 60 minutes or something?

Comment: It should be note that, when a new AT is issued using a RT, the authorization server can revoke the RT and issued a new one. Both new AT and RT are transmitted to the client. This behaviour is at the discretion of the authorization server and mainly depends on its security policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About security: You are right, it would not make much sense to use only one token to get another, but jwt authentication should only transmitted over HTTPS and to avoid man in the middle attacks CORS and other means (like client thumbprints) ought be used. RT's valid time must start only when AT is expired. And if you do not have to be stateless, you can e.g. save generated jwt on server and do not generate another until its expiration etc.
The timescales completely depend on the application. If its a financial system with API open to the world, times should be really short for AT and not much longer for RT, but if its a community site with no sensitive data RT should be really long for convenience is more important than top security. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks that did help a bit. But when you say "RT's valid time must start only when AT is expired," the RT is stored on the client to be sent to the server for an AT. I can't change the start/end time of the RT in the client. Only the server can do that ... ?

Or do you mean the start time of the RT is updated to reflect the end time of the AT when I pass the RT back to the server to request an AT ?

Comment: As the server generates the RT as well at the same request when AT is generated the server knows how to set it and then put BOTH in the authentication acknowledge response.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's kind of like a chain of times, e.g. AT[0,10], RT[10,100], where numbers in brackets indicate valid start/end times. That makes sense.

Comment: yes, and you can use a registered  "nbf" claim for that.

Comment: Yes "note before". I'm currently stateless, but I could easily become stateful as I could add the token data to the Users table...